# Is the expectation of a random variable simply a composite function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, random-variables, definition, expected-value

I want to strip away the language of measure theory to get to the essence of what a random variable is.

I am reading Probability and Random Processes  by Grimmett and Stirzaker, and the authors goes through this iterative construction process, whereby the expectation is defined at every step.

These steps can be simply boiled down to:

- Let $X$ be a simple function, $X = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^k x_i I_{A_i}$
  and then calling $E(X) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^k x_i P(A_i)$ the
  expectation
- Next, consider non-negative RVs, $X$ and show that the
  limit of the preceding expectation is this new expectation
- Do it
  again for random variables $X$ defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$

Viola, then you have this magic notation $\mathbb{E}(X) = \int_\Omega X(\omega) dP$. My goal is to reverse engineer this function and express it in the most tractable way.

I want to do away with this notation (in my opinion, confusing, as it abstracts away too much) and  try to understand exactly what function we are dealing with, and I have came up with the following: for any random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$,

$$
\textstyle \mathbb{E}(X):=f(\{x_{n,i}\}, \Omega, P) = \mathbb{E}(\max(\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^k x_{n,i} P(A_{n,i}),0) + \min(\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^k x_{n,i} P(A_{n,i}),0)]
$$
where $x_{n,i}$ is the $i$th component of simple functions $X_n: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}, X_n = \sum_{i = 1}^k x_{n,i} P(A_{n,i})$ and $A_{n,i}$ is the some partition of $\Omega$ associated with the same $X_n$.

Can someone chime in whether this is a valid definition for a random variable? Why not directly deal with this object, instead of hiding it with  $\mathbb{E}(X) = \int_\Omega X(\omega) dP$?

Comment: If one is *defining* $\mathbb{E}(X)$ the term being defined shoudn't typically appear on the right side of the defining equation (as well as the left).

Comment: @coffeemath Fixed

Comment: I still see the $\mathbb{E}$ but it is delayed until after the function $f$ applied in some way to your "component" (and can't see how applied). Also $f$ not defined...

Comment: I’ma keep it  with you chief....the RHS of your definition does *not* look better than $\int_\Omega X(\omega) dP$. The integral definition is awkward as a newcomer, but the price you pay in accessibility is made up in generality later.

Comment: If you like, the integral is just shorthand. But it makes sense to use shorthand because there is a bunch of theory that you need to set up in order to ensure that this definition behaves the way that you would really like it to behave. For example, that the value of $E(X)$ doesn't depend on how you measurably partition $\Omega$ along the limiting process. x

Comment: To put it another way, what you're saying would be like carrying around the entire Cauchy sequence equivalence class definition whenever you talk about a real number. It's cumbersome. Sometimes in math, something is what it does, rather than being what it's made of. For some students, "formal proof classes" (out of books like A Transition to Advanced Mathematics) wind up hiding this fact.

Comment: What does $X_n$ have to do with $X$? You did not say.